# update table values

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have a table called `RoomDetails` that contains the following columns:

```
room_no, room_type, room_rate, chk_in_date, chk_out_date, room_status

(pk)

1   regular 3000.0000   NULL    NULL    A
2   regular 3000.0000   NULL    NULL    A
.
.
15  regular 3000.0000   NULL    NULL    A
16  delux   5000.0000   NULL    NULL    A
17  delux   5000.0000   NULL    NULL    A
18  delux   5000.0000   NULL    NULL    A
.
.
24  delux   5000.0000   NULL    NULL    A
25  delux   5000.0000   NULL    NULL    A
26  superdelux  8000.0000   NULL    NULL    A
27  superdelux  8000.0000   NULL    NULL    A
.
35  superdelux  8000.0000   NULL    NULL    A
```

Now I have to udpade `chk_in_date` and `chk_out_date` whenever any customer books a room. The dates must be updated into `chk_in_date` and `chk_out_date` and also room status updated to `NA` (i.e NOT AVAILABLE)

Thus how do I write a procedure for this in SQL for SQL Server 2005 and coding in vb.net?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this if I understand what you need.
When customer books room use this:

```
UPDATE RoomDetails
SET chk_in_date = GETDATE(), 
    chk_out_date = NULL,
    room_status = "NA"
WHERE room_no = booked_room
```

When customer leaves room, use this:

```
UPDATE RoomDetails
SET chk_out_date = GETDATE(), 
    room_status = "A"
WHERE room_no = booked_room
```

Comment: @user1234119: I've just added another query in my answer. Is this what you need?

Comment: but the whenever  customer book room thne will be assign the room_noqury wiil be lik this
Update [TestDB].[dbo].[Room_details]
        SET [check_out_date]=@chkout
  where room_no=(Select room_no from room_details where room_status like'A')

Comment: @user1234119: I'm really in trouble understanding what you say. Anyway `booked_room` is room number your customer is booking or leaving.